# Converting a date field into the day of the year and then adding it into an empty field arcpy python arcgis

Tags: python, date, field, arcgis, arcpy

I am currently working on a project in ArcGIS where I have a bunch of feature classes that all contain a date field that represents the dates that the samples in the feature classes were taken.

I need to convert each of those dates (the field type is "date" not string or integer) in each of those feature classes into the day of the year and then add the day of the year into an empty field called `DOY`.

The dates are in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format but there are no leading zeros (7/4/15 instead of 07/04/15). The sample date field in each feature class are either named `Date`, `Sample_Dat` or `T0_Date`, but each feature class only contains one of those fields. The code that I have attached is what I have so far.

NOTE: The `arcpy.calculateField_management` should align with the `rows.updateRows` above it in each of the 3 cases but there was formatting issues when I copied the code over to this website that I could not fix.

EDIT: Whenever I try to run this code it does nothing and does not add the day of year to the DOY field.  Also, instead of giving a red X or a green check it will give a yellow triangle signaling a warning which is due to the fact that about 80% of the feature classes already have a "DOY" field but I included the addfield_management part at the beginning to account for the 20% that don't have a DOY field.  I thought by adding the elif statements it wouldn't give a warning sign and instead it would just loop until it reached a relevant statement.

```
import arcpy      
import datetime    
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()  
for fc in fcList:    
    if "DOY" not in arcpy.ListFields(fc):    
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc,"DOY","SHORT")    
    elif "DOY" in arcpy.ListFields(fc) and "Date" in arcpy.ListFields(fc):    
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "Date") as rows:    
            for row in rows:    
                rows.updateRow([datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%m/%d/%Y')])    
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,"DOY",row.timetuple().tm_yday)    
    elif "DOY" in arcpy.ListFields(fc) and "Sample_Dat" in arcpy.ListFields(fc):  
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,"Sample_Dat") as rows:    
            for row in rows  :  
                rows.updateRow([datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%m/%d/%Y')])    
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,"DOY",row.timetuple().tm_yday)    
    elif "DOY" in arcpy.ListFields(fc) and "T0_Date" in arcpy.ListFields(fc):     
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,"T0_Date") as rows:    
            for row in rows:    
                rows.updateRow([datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%m/%d,%Y')])                              
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,"DOY",row.timetuple().tm_yday)    
    else:    
        pass
```

Comment: The code is a bit inefficient, but it basically looks good. What happens when you run it? Are there errors? Does it not produce the desired outcome?

Comment: It doesn't produce the desired outcome.  If I change the last "else: pass" to "else: print 'something' " it would print "something" for every feature class instead of doing the day of year stuff.  Which is part I am having trouble fixing and need help on.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem, then. Please edit your question to include what is going wrong and I'll see if I can write up an answer.

Comment: I edited the original post let me know if that is good enough or if I need to do something else.

Comment: Nevermind I just saw your post i will try that now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a datetime object into the correct format, day of the year, arcpy python arcgis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971883/how-to-get-a-datetime-object-into-the-correct-format-day-of-the-year-arcpy-pyt)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I think the issue is that you're checking if DOY exists in every case, instead of creating it where need be and updating it in every case. Try the following:

EDIT: I checked the documentation, and it looks like arcpy.ListFields() returns a Field object, not a string. I've updated my code.

```python
import arcpy
import datetime

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    # get fields ONCE for each FC, and only get the fields we care about
    fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.name in ("DOY", "Date", "Sample_Dat", "T0_Date")]

    # add desired field if it does not exist
    if "DOY" not in fields:
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc,"DOY","SHORT")
    # otherwise, remove "DOY" from the list of fields.
    else:
        fields.pop("DOY")

    if len(fields) == 0:
        print "No DATE field for FC", fc
    else:
        # the remaining item in fields should be the other date column.
        # NOTE: this MAY HAVE UNEXPRECTED RESULTS if you can have more than one of the listed date columns in a FC.
        dtm_field = fields[0]

        # now that we've ensured that the desired "DOY" field exists, we can update it from the other date field.
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, dtm_field) as rows:
            count = 0
            for row in rows:
                # debugging printout so you can see progress being made
                if count % 1000 == 0:
                    print count, "rows updated"
                count += 1

                ## this assumes that all date fields have the same date pattern
                #rows.updateRow([datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%m/%d/%Y')])
                #arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "DOY", row.timetuple().tm_yday)

                # do you actually need to update the datetime field? If you only need to update DOY, you can do the following:
                dtm = datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%m/%d/%Y')
                arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "DOY", dtm.timetuple().tm_yday)
```

Comment: When I ran the code it did not work properly.  It printed "No DATE field for fc" for every feature class, even if the feature class had a date field, and did not add anything to those feature class's DOY field. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: It also gave the same warning message that the field already contained a DOY field.  I wonder if moving that part of the code to the bottom would affect that or not?

Comment: So I was getting two error messages, the first is this "Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: which is the fields.pop("DOY") line I believe. im not familiar with .pop so I am not sure what this could be.  The other one, which I was getting yesterday and haven't gotten yet today because its further down in the code but I think it was the count % 1000 == 0 line.  I'm not sure what the exact error message was but I am not sure how to fix that because I wasn't familiar with that part of the code either

Comment: another thing about the fields.pop code that I don't know is relevant or not but there are other fields in the feature classes other than just date and DOY. Each field contains other data fields and the date is just the day that the data in those fields were collected.

Comment: I took out the .pop and tried to just put else: pass there instead and then I ran the code again.  There was no error for the % 1000 but there was one that says that "strptime() argument 1 must be string, not list" @Triggernometry